# Julia scoping specifics: defining closure within loop

Tags: julia

I am learning Julia using [Ivo Balbaert's book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/julia-10-programming/9781788999090/). He uses the following example:

```
anon = Array{Any}(undef, 2)
for i = 1:2
    anon[i] = () -> println(i)
    i += 1
end
```

Now calling the two functions in this array outputs:

```
julia> anon[1](); anon[2]()
2
3
```

I fail to understand why the output is 2, 3 instead of 1, 2. At the first pass through the loop `i = 1`, so that `anon[1] = () -> println(1)`. The author continues:

> Here, both `anon[1]` and `anon[2]` are anonymous functions. When they are
>   called with `anon[1]()` and `anon[2]()`, they print `2` and `3` (the values of
>   i when they were created plus one).

The expected behavior is then achieved by using `let`. What I am missing in this explanation, however, is how Julia scoping rules operate in order to produce the first (unexpected) result of 2, 3. In other words, how do the values 2 and 3 come to be? Could someone please explain this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty tricky. You need to know two things:

- within a `for` loop variable `i` gets a fresh binding on every iteration (I guess you know it - I do not know Ivo's book, but from your question I guess this is what he is discussing in it)
- in Julia closures are implemented via a creation of an object that captures a variable from an outer scope and then it can access it

Now to explain the second point have a look at the following (I assume you have run the code above):

```
julia> anon[1].i
Core.Box(2)

julia> anon[1].i.contents
2
```

And you can see that `anon[1]` has boxed the binding to `i` that was present in the first iteration of the loop. As in the second loop the binding to `i` is fresh `anon[2]` has a reference to this fresh binding.

You can even access this memory location like this:

```
julia> anon[1].i.contents = 100
100

julia> anon[1]()
100
```

or even like this (not recommended):

```
julia> for i = 1:2
           anon[i] = () -> println(i)
           anon[i].i.contents = 100 + i
           i += 1
           println(i)
       end
102
103

julia> anon[1]()
102

julia> anon[2]()
103
```

Finally note that within a single iteration of the loop assigning to variable `i` does not change the binding (you are writing to the same memory location).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess what is confusing here is that the function definition occurs earlier in the loop than the increase of `i`. I went to R, which I am more familiar there, but the behavior there turned out to be similar. Namely, it is the value of `i` at the exit of the loop that counts.  Moreover, the `i` in the iterator definition seems to be different from the `i` in the function definition. The first one is an array of type `{Any, 1}`, whereas the former is `Int64`. Am I getting this right more or less?

Comment: Inside the loop `i` is a variable that has type `Int64` and points to some address in memory. Therefore in statements `anon[i]`, `println(i)` and `i += 1` variable `i` refer to exactly the same address in memory (the value stored in this address changes though) within a single iteration of the loop. However, with each loop Julia assigns a fresh binding to `i`, so in each iteration`i` points to a different memory location. Is this clearer now?