# Closure, anonymous function, why not being the values when they were created

Tags: julia

Run the following snippet in Julia 1.0

```
anon = Array{Any}(undef, 2)
for i = 1:2
    anon[i] = ()-> println(i)
    i += -1
end
anon[2]()
anon[1]()
```

The results are `1` and `0`. Why not be `2` and `1` (the values of `i` when they were created)? I know that the `i += -1` will not affect the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

[Julia scoping specifics: defining closure within loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653670)  gives an explanation: *with each loop Julia assigns a fresh binding to `i`, so in each iteration `i` points to a different memory location*.